LinearRegression: NaN Error even after having Simple Imputer in the pipeline
I am on the classic California Housing Dataset trying to predict the median house value. So, the dataset contains NaN values in total bedrooms. I used the Simple Imputer to replace them with median values but when I go on to train the model I still get NaN values. Now, the strategy used with the imputer was median, so traditional methods for constant strategy don't work. I have checked the dataframe and there aren't any after my preprocessing. But when I try to preprocess and run the model together via a pipeline, I don't know what goes wrong. I have copied some of the code that's relevant linked the Jupyter notebook with the rest of the code for reference. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gpaI2xJE2tY0gxEAD1oFGUGsBgRIal5q?usp=sharing
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
class ClusterSimilarity(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, n_clusters=10, gamma=1.0,random_state=None):
    self.n_clusters=n_clusters
    self.gamma=gamma
    self.random_state=random_state
  def fit(self, X,y=None,sample_weight=None):
    self.kmeans_=KMeans(self.n_clusters,random_state=self.random_state,n_init=10)
    self.kmeans_.fit(X,sample_weight=sample_weight)
    return self
  def transform(self,X):
    return rbf_kernel(X, self.kmeans_.cluster_centers_,gamma=self.gamma)
  def get_feature_names_out(self,names=None):
    return [f"Cluster {i} similarity" for i in range(self.n_clusters)]

def column_ratio(X):
  return X[:,[0]]/X[:,[1]]
def ratio_name(function_transformer,feature_names_in):
  return['ratio']
def ratio_pipeline():
  return make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='median',missing_values=pd.NA),FunctionTransformer(column_ratio,feature_names_out=ratio_name),StandardScaler())
log_pipeline=make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='median',missing_values=pd.NA),FunctionTransformer(np.log,feature_names_out='one-to-one'),StandardScaler())
cluster_simil=ClusterSimilarity(n_clusters=10,gamma=1.,random_state=69)
default_num_pipeline=make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='median',missing_values=pd.NA),StandardScaler())
preprocessing=ColumnTransformer([("bedrooms_per_room",ratio_pipeline(),["total_bedrooms","total_rooms"]),("rooms_per_house",ratio_pipeline(),
 ["total_rooms","households"]),("people_per_house",ratio_pipeline(),["population","households"]),
  ("log",log_pipeline,["total_bedrooms","total_rooms","population","households","median_income"]),("coordinates_adjustments",cluster_simil,["latitude","longitude"]),
   ("cat",cat_pipeline,make_column_selector(dtype_include=object))],remainder=default_num_pipeline)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg=make_pipeline(preprocessing, LinearRegression())
lin_reg.fit_transform(housing,housing_labels)

I tried using SimpleImputer in my pipeline to remove the NaN values but even after that I'm getting NaN Error. I manually checked my pipeline and tested it out for NaN values, but the data was empty implying no presence of NaN values but when I tried using it for a Linear Regression model, I got NaN error. I also used the missing_values as both pd.NA and np.none besides None and all do nothing.

Your imputers all happen early in pipelines, maybe one of the other transformers introduces NaNs? Division by zero, log of zero, etc? Where do the NaNs appear when you run preprocessing.fit_transform(housing)?

@BenReiniger That's the worst part about it. I made a garbage_housing dataframe to just apply preprocessing and then ran a check for NaN.  The output for the head function shows an empty dataframe:
housing_prepared=preprocessing.fit_transform(housing)
null_rows_idx = garbage_housing.isnull().any(axis=1)
print(garbage_housing.loc[null_rows_idx].head(5))```
I've publicly shared the notebook, you can see the everything.
